# How can I step up 6.5V to 10V?

Tags: led, buck-boost, voltage-amplification

I'm working with a [buck/boost LED driver](https://www.ledsupply.com/led-drivers/flexblock-buck-boost-dc-led-driver) that uses a 0->10V dimmer input. I would like to use the output of an [open-source LED module](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?1539753-Open-Source-Lights-Arduino-based-RC-Light-Controller) as a switch for the LED driver. The LED module outputs 0 V in the "off" condition and 6.5 V in the "on" condition. I want to use one of the channels to control a high-power Cree LED using the buck/boost driver. So I would like to boost the 6.5 V output of the LED module to the 10 V required by the LED driver for full brightness. Is an op-amp the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you need an analog gain (i.e. do you care what happens when the input to your "step up" circuit is 1.3 or 2.5 V)? Or do you just need a digital level translation (the only input voltages you care about are 0 V and 6.5 V)?

Comment: I do not need an analog transition. The input will really only be 0 or 6.5V.

Comment: It looks like you could easily run that open source LED module off of 10V and make your life much easier. Just connect 10V (from a wall wart or something) to Alt Power and do not install JP2 (RX power). You still need to supply V+ from somewhere to power the rest of the board.

Comment: I'm limited to the power inputs available on an RC truck - namely, a battery (either 2S, 3S or 4S LiPo) and an open channel on the receiver (which is what I'm using), which supplies 6.5 V as long as the ESC is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

In comments you said,

> I do not need an analog transition. The input will really only be 0 or 6.5V

In that case, the easiest solution is probably a comparator with an open-drain output. Based on the datasheet of your LED driver, no pull-up is required because the the input circuit on the driver sources a small current.

In this schematic, U1 is any comparator with open-drain output that can handle the input and output voltage ranges you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHB1Xs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Wow, this is awesome... I assume that OUT is the 10 V output but what is IN?

Comment: @user127813, IN is the signal coming from your "open source LED model" at either 0 or 6.5 V.